# Embedding PowerBI reports and authenticate in web application without using Azure AD

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-embedded, powerbi-datasource, power-bi-report-server

I have embedded power bi report public access url in my web application, which is not authenticated. Is their any way i can authenticate the report without using Azure AD? Please do reply with solution.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Are you using the Power BI embedded service? Or did you publish a report to public from Power BI...

Comment: Yes i am using. Yes have publish report to public .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you talking about 'Publish-To-Web' solution (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/service-publish-to-web), if so - no, there is no way to authenticate access to such published report.

For getting authenticated access to embedded report, you should use PowerBI embedded (see https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/power-bi-embedded)